# Run multi threads in servlets

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have couple of processes (calling to a 3rd party service and get response, query database and get results, do some IO operations etc) to be executed in my servlets. Moreover, those processes are time consuming and if the 3rd party call which is the first process,  response fails, the rest of processes should be terminated too.

I am to run all these processes as multi threads using Executors.  As soon as possible, the response of first process is available, the servlet should send response ( redirect to a page ) . When the rest of all process are finished, the output should be sent to the page again (something like push to the browser), or redirect to another page, ( but then want to have the access to the already running rest of threads.

My first attempt was to send ajax requests from the browser and handle all these processes. But it is less secure. So, let me know an approach to run these threads and once first process is done, send the response and later return the rest of outputs.

Comment: You can't push to the browser, you have to pull from the browser

Comment: @NitinDandriyal Well, you can push to the client using WebSockets or SSE (Server-sent Events)...

Comment: Is your application HTML5 and supporting websockets?

Comment: @aksappy. Thanks for your reply. I have to have supported older IE versions and I can't use HTML 5.

Comment: But, requirements like yours is exactly why ajax and websockets was invented

Comment: @Débora you'll have to be more specific than that. "Older IE versions" - how old? Not all the way back to IE6 I hope?

Comment: What did you mean by AJAX is less secure?

Comment: @aksappy, Thanks again. do u believe most of common browsers support web sockets and without html5, this can be achieved ? I use servlet 2.4, java 7

Comment: @Gimby, IE 8 and new versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options after knowing which IE version we have to support

1. Use an AJAX based implementation.

Using AJAX and HTTP POST, trigger your services one by one. Also make sure that promises are maintained in order to keep a clean state of requests. You can also use ajax chaining, if you have to follow order of completion as well. Please note AJAX as such has no security limitations (see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/is-ajax-fundamentally-insecure)), it is just an API which uses HTTP methods to call server, in an asynchronous way. So if your server has security, AJAX can/need inherit that security.

2. Use a websockets based implementation

Since IE8 does not support websockets natively, you can use a custom api such as [this](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js). Please note this will have some compatibility issues going forward, but for now there are no visible impacts. Call the servlet which will trigger different threads, and send back the data after completion of threads. If your server has websocket-api.jar in its server lib, then you can code the server side of it very easily. See [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html)

Comment: Thank v much. Websocket required HTTP 5.. :(  + java ee 7

Comment: Did you mean HTML5? No, that is what I have given in the 2 option first link. You can use https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket as a startup for your server side as well, which does not require Java EE7, but I have not attempted

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation in this situation is to make the entire page asynchronous.  Send request, kick off threads and return immediately.  The threads can populate a common object contained in session, write to files or a database.  Once complete, set a flag to show any subsequent requests from the client (polling requests, etc) that you're finished and the page can be built.

You can present the interim page in various ways ("Check back" message, polling with progress bar, et. al.).

Comment: Thanks ur answer. But I have some concerns. I don't use HttpSession directly and not sure the load balancer redirect the request to which server (No sticky sesssions ).

Comment: If you don't have sticky sessions, you're left with persisted sessions.  So the threads collect results and write to a database.